# what to use instead of update_all and update_attributes? (someone says they are deprecated)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw that `update_all` and `update_attributes` are deprecated:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

What should one use to update parameters of one/multiple records?

Comment: it's gone in Rails 4. Are you using Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: Rails 3. thought Rails 4 is still beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `update_columns` is what you are looking for.

> Updates the given attributes of an object, without calling save, hence skipping validations and callbacks.
>   https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2d9e5a26a10e5f83f9b3ac465bd45b2e15a0bc2a

```
# Rails 4.0.0
User.first.update_columns({:name => "sebastian", :age => 25})
```

Comment: Rubocop says: Avoid using `update_columns` because it skips validations. (convention:Rails/SkipsModelValidations)